# Get the exact coordinates of a particular element itself with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coordinates

I am trying to get the coordinates of a div with JQuery. I am currently using this method:

```
     $("#draw_area").click(function (e) {
             var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
             var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
         });
```

However, I realised that if I have html elements on top of the div "draw_area", it will give me different "y". I do not want that. What I want is to get the exact/relative coordinates of that particular div, and the coordinates are always the same regardless whether there are other elements
**EDIT**:
**above the div or next to the div**. 
Can someone please tell me how I could achieve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [.offset()](https://api.jquery.com/offset/), which gives you the position relative to the `document`, as opposed to [.position()](https://api.jquery.com/position/), which gives you the position relative to the offset parent.

```
     $("#draw_area").click(function (e) {
         var o = $(this).offset();
         var x = o.left;
         var y = o.top;
     });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, your code still gives me different y if there is some element(s) on top of the "draw_area div, which is not what I want

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "on top", but if you're layering elements over each other, it could be that `this` isn't what you're expecting.  You could try `$(e.target).offset();` instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. What I want is to get the exact/relative coordinates of that particular div, and the coordinates are always the same regardless whether there are other elements
above the div or next to the div.